# If your opponent leaves the game, is that considered a full victory?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've been watching some high level player's replays on SC2, and I noticed that when one opponent knows he'll lose, he just leaves the game.

Is that considered a victory for the player who did not leave? Is it the same *kind of victory* as completely destroying the enemy (without him leaving), or is there some kind of difference (stats-wise)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.

You should receive full points.  No part of the point calculation or the change to your rating is reflected by anything that happens in game.

On an unrelated note it is considered proper etiquette to say "gg" before leaving in such a manner.

---

Now I'm sure someone will mention pro-matches in reference to this question.  When participating in a tournament with Bo5 style matches (Best of 5 games, or First to 3 wins) experienced tournament players will actually delay a final push when they believe they have 100% chance of victory.  The purpose is to cause the losing player to exert additionally mental stress in trying to win an unwinnable game and thus have them "tired" for the next game in the series.

While this behavior is not considered bad manners and is often times a signifier that you are playing against a tournament pro, it leads many professional gamers to bow out earlier than you might normally expect.  Because they know they still have to play potentially 4 more games, top players will often quit if their opponent has gained a significant advantage at any point in the game.

The corollary to this behavior is that in a game `N` situation (or game `N-1` if you're losing `floor(N/2)` to `floor(N/2)-1`), losing players will often stay longer as defeat implies elimination.

Comment: The "gg" thing is a shame, what I like more about strategy games are the last moments when you get to see the base getting completely destroyed -- all the replays I watched let me wanting more when the gged it.

Comment: @Juan you can continue playing, if wanton destruction fits your pallet.

Comment: @Juan Manuel, I often wish my opponent would just gg and get it over with.  There are times where it is clear I am dominating, but it may still take a while to completely tear down a base.  An extreme example would be when mass Void Ray fails to my mass corrupters, but the opponent built a hundred photon cannons, and I have to tech up to brood lords to slowly but inexorably pick them off.

Comment: @Peter or when he flies away his last barracks and you know he doesn't have any minerals so he can't afford to build more units, but he's just trying to hide long enough so you give up, and you lost all your workers but you still have a Raven left, so you have to build up the energy to HS Missile him to death... just as soon as you find him.

Comment: @Peter, I respect fighting and fighting until your last breath :)

Comment: @tzenes hah that is an even more extreme example than mine - I was thinking of times where I am crushing but just can't finish off the base.  waiting for the energy to build up would be agonizing.  I know this is probably not a high priority item for Blizzard, but it seems easy enough to fix - something like "flying buildings are revealed after X minutes of player having no CC on the ground, or after X minutes of no unit production, or anything else that wouldn't affect normal play but stop the lame Terrans.

Comment: @Peter I think I mostly just hate it because they're Terran.  You're already playing an overpowered race you don't have to try and annoy me to death.

Comment: One thing I hate is the reverse. when it's clear I'm going to lose and the other player says "gg". That should be my prerogative, it seems excessively rude to presume I'm about to surrender (even if I am). When that happens I often stretch as long as I possibly can, training my micro skills a bit. So uh, don't do that if you want a fast win.

Comment: @Wds there was another question where I talked about the premptive "gg" at length, but I can't find it now.  Suffice to say this is "bad manners."  There is nothing you can do about BM, its annoying and you kind of have to let it go.